# App working in emulator and not in device

Tags: mysql, database, android-asynctask

My APP es simple, just a mysql insert with a Asynctask.
It works fine running on simulator and when i change the ip 10.0.2.2 to the ip of my pc, it doesn't work, I mean, i dont have errors but the insert is not done.

(They are in the same network, ip address is right)

Why it could be?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is not the ip of you computer but `the ip of your network` (your router). If you are connected in the same wifi you can put your local ip (something like `192.168.*.*`).

Comment: Given you've shown nothing useful, like actual code, we'll have to blame it on PEBKAC/PICNIC

Comment: @LolWalid I did it. The ip of my mysql server is 192.168.1.37. What Im trying to say is why it works for localhost with the emulator and doesnt work in my device, the ip of my mysql server if they are in the same network.